# Ruby webdriver xpath element not visible error

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find the count from xpath of the element below

```
wait.until {browser.find_element(:xpath, "//*[contains(@class, 'line active_line')]").displayed? }

lines_count= browser.find_elements(:xpath, "//*[contains(@class, 'line active_line')]").size

puts "Number of Line(s) For #{name} is #{lines_count}"
```

i am getting (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError) error if the xpath is not present on page.

How to handle this error?

Comment: Give the relevant HTML part also.

Comment: This is ruby webdriver code..it doesn't have html part

Comment: On which webpage you ran this code? Give an relevant excerpt of that

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't have html part? Where did you get your `(@class, 'line active_line')` from?

Comment: i tried this on my project..

Comment: What about checking if it exists first?
if @driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//*[contains(@class, 'line active_line')]").size() > 0

Comment: i am not checking if the xpath is exists or not...it gives count if xpath is present otherwise it gives ElementNotVisible error..How to handle if xpath is not present on page???

Comment: Error is findElementInternal_': Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/div[2]/a"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)

Comment: I tried these two options on code...no use still getting same error 1. if (browser.find_elements(:xpath, "//*[contains(@class, 'line active_line')]").displayed?) 2. wait.until{browser.find_elements(:xpath, "//*[contains(@class, 'line active_line')]").displayed?}

lines_count =browser.find_elements(:xpath, "//*[contains(@class, 'line active_line')]").size 

puts "Number of Line(s) For #{name} is #{lines_count}"

rescue

puts "Number of Line(s) For #{name} is 0"

end

Comment: what about some try-catch eqvivalent in ruby? Sry, i am not familiar with ruby, but i think it is called rescue.

Comment: if the xpath does not resolve to a WebElement, it should throw NoSuchElement, not ElementNotVisible. At least it does so in java

Comment: i can't catch this below error using rescure                       Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)